# How to have a link inside an already clickable area?

Tags: html, hyperlink

From a previous question I learned that a  tag cannot be inside another  tag.

So do you know a solution for having a link or a button inside a click able area ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript to redirect the page:

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">
    <a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a>
    <a href="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</a>
    <div>Clicking anywhere else goes to Google</div>
</div>
```